# Debian 9: fatal error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found, even though libcurl4-openssl-dev is installed?

Tags: debian, libcurl

Essentially as the title says: Debian 9: fatal error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found, even though libcurl4-openssl-dev is installed?

config.log:

```
configure:5741: checking for curl-config
configure:5759: found /usr/bin/curl-config
configure:5771: result: /usr/bin/curl-config
configure:5782: checking for the version of libcurl
configure:5789: result: 7.52.1
configure:5796: checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2
configure:5809: result: yes
configure:5850: checking whether libcurl is usable
configure:5884: aarch64-linux-android-clang -o conftest -O3 -mfpu=neon    conftest.c -lcurl  >&5
conftest.c:31:10: fatal error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found
#include <curl/curl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
configure:5884: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "cpuminer"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "cpuminer"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.3"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "cpuminer 1.0.3"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "cpuminer"
| #define VERSION "1.0.3"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_ENDIAN_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYSLOG_H 1
| #define HAVE_DECL_BE32DEC 0
| #define HAVE_DECL_LE32DEC 0
| #define HAVE_DECL_BE32ENC 0
| #define HAVE_DECL_LE32ENC 0
| #define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
| #define HAVE_ALLOCA 1
| #define HAVE_GETOPT_LONG 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <curl/curl.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
| /* Try and use a few common options to force a failure if we are
|    missing symbols or can't link. */
| int x;
| curl_easy_setopt(NULL,CURLOPT_URL,NULL);
| x=CURL_ERROR_SIZE;
| x=CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION;
| x=CURLOPT_WRITEDATA;
| x=CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER;
| x=CURLOPT_STDERR;
| x=CURLOPT_VERBOSE;
| if (x) {;}
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5898: result: no
configure:5989: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

The headers are in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/, of which I symlinked in both /usr/include/curl and /usr/local/include/curl.

Have I done anything silly? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to specify the include directory at compile time.

To list your default include paths you can run the command

```
# clang -xc -E -v -
```

This will list where headers are searched for. E.g.

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The nifty tool pkg-config can help you locate the needed paths for libcurl.

```
# pkg-config --cflags libcurl
-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

From this we see that your path is included, but the compiler that is complaining is aarch64-linux-android-clang.

Possible answer

Try to run

```
# aarch64-linux-android-clang -xc -E -v -
```

and see if that reveals that the paths searched do not contain the header in question. You might also need to get headers (and libcurl) for aarch64.

Good luck!